# Proxypass for certain folder

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, proxypass

Using `Apache (Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)`, `ProxyPass (mod_proxy)`, how can I serve content from one host to a folder on another host?

#### Example:

```
pears.com/folder
oranges.com/folder
```

I would like requests made on **oranges.com/folder** to be served the *content* that is in **pears.com/folder**. oranges.com/folder does not exist.

I tried some of the examples from, [apache.org/docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html). 
In **orange's** virtualhost config:

```
ProxyHTMLStripComments on  
ProxyRequests off  
SetOutputFilter proxy-html  
ProxyHTMLDoctype XHTML  
SSLProxyEngine on  
SetEnv no-gzip 1  

<Location /folder>
   ProxyPass pears.com/folder  
   ProxyPassReverse pears.com/folder  
   Order allow,deny  
   Allow from all  
</Location>
```

The error I receive is,

> The webpage at https://pears.com/folder/ might be temporarily down or
>   it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

---

**Edit** - The solution was to disable compression on the pears server

Comment: Sorry,I should have included that.

I tried some of the examples from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html.

From host2's virtualhost config, ProxyPass "/folder" "http://host2.com/folder" 

I think I just need a more relevant example.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your question, if you expect someone will answer. There’s an “edit” link right below your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable compression on the pears server.